# Netbeans run failed

Tags: c++, netbeans, netbeans-8, exit-code

I know this might be a stupid question.

I'm having some issues with NetBeans configuration on Windows 10. I have correctly downloaded / installed Cygwin and so on. But when I try to run my code (which is wrong, but I want to know why), it just says "3416 cygwin_exception::open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to progtrest4.exe.stackdump" . And then exit value 35,584.

On another computer I runned the same code and million errors appeared about mainly wrong memory management.

The build is totally ok, compiler doesn't say a thing except for "Build successful".

If I had to post the code, it would be too long, besides there's something wrong with conf of NetBeans. 
Anyone has ever experienced this ?

What could I do to repare it ? Thanks so much.

Comment: Hi, George. It would be very helpful if you could provide a link to your code. GitHub? Zip file somewhere?

Comment: https://gist.github.com/gutwijir/db9945fe3a806430f95be27f28e56717 I am new to GitHub, so if this link doesn't work, just tell me :) basically the program is a simple mailserver (the task is to correctly make deep / shallow copy)

Comment: I just saw it’s a program in C. Let’s wait for the specialists:)